# parsing in an external xml feed into php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

Im really new to php and im trying to load in data from an external xml feed into a php document, then use that data to generate an output.

The xml feed im using is - http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N

What im trying to do is generate a list of 'markets' and there names, so as the xml feed stands at the time of writing the first 3 items in the list would be :

- Scottish Division 1 - Outright - Outright
- Dumbarton v Hamilton - 1st Half Result/2nd Half Result
- Dumbarton v Hamilton - Match Handicaps

at the moment im trying to use the code bellow to achieve this, but im getting nowhere quickly with it, any ideas on what im doing wrong here ?

*just a further piece of background, im using php 5.4.4, am i right in thinking that simplexml comes already pre installed.. so i dont need to add any thing additional here ?*

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N');

foreach ($xml->market as $event) {
  echo $event;
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

It is working right here. Try to print_r($xml);

Comment: @IvoPereira im managing to get the whole feed using print_r($xml); but im having trouble picking it the <market id="39970574" name="Scottish Division 1 - Outright - Outright"    part out using the foreach loop

Comment: Hi @sam, I  need the WSDL for this old api (since v2 is protected by an ApiKey that I cannot manage to get). Do you have the wsdl by any chance?? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to drill down through the xml to get the markets, and then get the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) of the market:

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N');

foreach ($xml->response->williamhill->class->type as $type) {
  $type_attrib = $type->attributes();
  echo "<p><h2>Type ".$type_attrib['id'].": ".$type_attrib['name']."</h2>";
  foreach ($type->market as $event) {
    $event_attributes = $event->attributes();
    echo $event_attributes['name']."<br />";
    //commented out the following which prints all attributes
    //replaced by above to just print the name
    /*
    echo "<p>";
    foreach($event->attributes() as $attrib=>$value) {
      echo "$attrib: $value <br />";
    }
    echo "</p>";
    */
  }
  echo "</p>";
}
```

Comment: By the way, while you are testing you should save the xml file to a local file and just load it from there, it will be a lot quicker and save bandwidth.

Comment: thanks bencoder, this works to format the output of the xml data, but it outputs every attribute given, rather than just the name

Comment: Hi @sam, I changed it so it will only print the name part. I commented out the part which prints all the attributes so you can compare to help you understand

Comment: thanks very much for that, it really helps to be able to pick it apart and see what each bit does. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could for example show the name of participants and respective odds doing this:

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N');


$data = $xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market;
$ps = $data->participant;
foreach($ps as $p)
{
    echo $p['name']." - ".$p['odds']."<br />";
}

?>
```